# Reduce gc_grace_seconds to 0 for TTL'ed data in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Does it make sense to reduce gc_grace_seconds to 0 (or some other really low #) if table only contains TTL'ed data (with no manual deletes)? Table has a default_time_to_live set of 30 days.  Also, as mentioned [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTable.html#tabProp__cqlTableGc_grace_seconds)

> In a single-node cluster, this property can safely be set to zero. You
>   can also reduce this value for tables whose data is not explicitly
>   deleted — for example, tables containing only data with TTL set,

More details of the schema.

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
user_uuid uuid,
ts bigint,
... //skipped a few columns
PRIMARY KEY (user_uuid, ts, event_uuid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC, event_uuid ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 'compaction_window_size': '24', 'compaction_window_unit': 'HOURS', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 2592000
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful, as with `gc_grace_seconds` you effectively disable hints collection, so if the node is down even for 5 minutes, you'll need to do a repair. In Cassandra 3.0, hints obey value `gc_grace_seconds` and if it's shorter then max_hints_window, then the hints will be collected for that time period only... But you can reduce this value to several hours if necessary, as it was hinted in linked documentation.

See this [very good blog post](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/03/21/hinted-handoff-gc-grace-demystified.html) on that topic.